# How to search for a string beginning with a certain value?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, search, wildcard

I am searching an array and trying to find object descriptions. The issue i am having is trying to use a wildcard. How can I search my array for Values starting with "Description:".

```
int[] poss = textlist.Select((b, i) => b == "Description:*" ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();

string[] Description = new string[poss.Length - 1];

foreach (int pos in poss)
{
    Description = textlist[pos];
}
```

Comment: `b.Contains("Description")`

Comment: or `b.StartsWith( "Description:" )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do:

```
Description = textlist.Where(s => s.StartsWith("Description:")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] poss = textlist.Select((b, i) => 
    b.StartsWith("Description") ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();
```